# How can I add <div> tag using Sgml Reader?

Tags: html, sgml

I am trying to wrap an `img tag` with `div tag` using Sgml reader and XElement
Here is my code:

`currentImageElement.AddBeforeSelf("< div >");` (without spaces)

The problem is it escapes the < and > chars, the result in the source is: `& lt; div & gt;`
Is there any way to unescape those tags so that it will be a real div tag and not text?

Comment: try this `currentImageElement.AddBeforeSelf("\< div \>");`

Comment: still escapes the < and >.. any other idea ?